# How can I disable submit form button until form is filled using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to disable the submit button but it is not re-enabling after there is text in the input field. How can I fix this?

```
    <form>
    <div class="col-lg-10 mb-3">
      <div class="input-group mycustom">
        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="Enter Your Name" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <input type="submit"  id="register" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm rounded-0" id="inputGroupPrepend2" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<a href = "highscores.html"> High Scores</a>
```

Jquery:

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
});
```

})()

Comment: use .prop, eg: $('#register').prop('disabled', true) and $('#register').prop('disabled', false).  I would also read about jQuery's sizzle engine and why you want to avoid it. Hint use a target syntax of $('form').find('input') instead of what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `id's` attributes in your `submit` button hence why you are having trouble with your `code`. One id is `inputGroupPrepend2` and other is `register` - you can **not** have both in input

To `disable` the button `use` [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method and set to `true` if you want to disable and `false` when you want to `enable` it.

```
$('#register').prop('disabled', true); //disable
```

I have simplified your `code` and is working as expected.

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#register').prop('disabled', true); //disable 
      } else {
        $('#register').prop('disabled', false); //enable
      }
    });
  })
});
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#register').prop('disabled', true); //disable 
      } else {
        $('#register').prop('disabled', false); //enable
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="col-lg-10 mb-3">
    <div class="input-group mycustom">
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="Enter Your Name" aria-describedby="register" required>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-secondary btn-smrounded-0" id="register" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<a href="highscores.html"> High Scores</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

*The > combinator selects nodes that are **direct children** of the first element.*

[Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Your `keyup` wasn't firing at all as well as `$('form > input').each(function() {` as that did not select input at al...

```js
(function() {
$('form * input').keyup(function() {
console.log(true);
    var empty = false;
    $('form * input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
});

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="col-lg-10 mb-3">
    <div class="input-group mycustom">
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="Enter Your Name" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input type="submit" id="register" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm rounded-0" id="inputGroupPrepend2" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<a href="highscores.html"> High Scores</a>
```

Comment: its not working for me. For reference, here are my sources: 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="db\index.js"></script>

Comment: Why would you have two jquery sources? @AiyaSiddig who knows what else is wrong... You need to make [mre]. I fixed The code you presented in question...

Comment: @AiyaSiddig please update your question with more code. Obviously problem is somewhere else. Also check your browser consol log for errors

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function(){

    var empty = false;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
  })
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update the bottom bit of code to this.

```
if (empty) {
            if ($('#register').is(':disabled')) {
                $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
            } 
            else {
                $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
  };
```